# Possible to add variables in email when sending via Curl?

Tags: bash, curl

I am using [Curl](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/smtp) to send simple email alerts:

```
curl smtp://mail.example.com --mail-from me@example.com --mail-rcpt \
to@example.com --upload-file email.txt
```

email.txt content:

```
From: John <me@example.com>
To: Joe <to@example.com>
Subject: Example email
Date: Wed, 26 Oct 2022 08:45:16    

Welcome to this example email.
```

Is it possible to have variables inside `email.txt` (e.g., make the date dynamic `date` or include bash user `who`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a GNU gettext utility called [`envsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#envsubst-Invocation), which replaces variables on its standard input with their values. For example:

```bash
$ export DATE=$(date +'%F %T')
$ echo '$DATE' | envsubst
2022-10-25 13:17:51
```

Notice that `echo '$DATE'` prints `$DATE`, literally, as the variable isn't expanded by the shell due to the single quotes.

To use that for your example, you could set the desired values in the environment:

```bash
export FROM='me@example.com'
export TO='to@example.com'
export DATE=$(date +'%F %T')
```

then update the email to use the variables:

```
From: John <$FROM>
To: Joe <$TO>
Subject: Example email
Date: $DATE

Welcome to this example email.
```

and then use `envsubst` and a process substitution in your command:

```bash
curl smtp://mail.example.com \
    --mail-from "$FROM" \
    --mail-rcpt "$TO" \
    --upload-file <(envsubst < email.txt)
```

where the output of `envsubst < email.txt` is

```
From: John <me@example.com>
To: Joe <to@example.com>
Subject: Example email
Date: 2022-10-25 13:23:44

Welcome to this example email.
```

Instead of process substitution, you could also use a pipeline and the special `-` file to read from standard input:

```bash
envsubst < email.txt \
    | curl smtp://mail.example.com \
        --mail-from "$FROM" \
        --mail-rcpt "$TO" \
        --upload-file -
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the details.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help you (see man envsubst):

```
$ cat test.txt
current date is ${CURRENT_DATE}

$ export CURRENT_DATE=$(date); cat test.txt | envsubst | curl bla-bla
```